# UserControl background property Brush binding does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

Hello i am trying to initialize usercontrol with bacground which is binded in viewmodel. In model color is set but dependency property does not take it.

HeaderCropper xaml :

```
<UserControl x:Class="x.CustomControls.x"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:converters="clr-x.Converters"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"

         Width="{Binding CropperWidth,ElementName=HeaderCropper}"
         Height="{Binding CropperHeight,ElementName=HeaderCropper}"
         x:Name="HeaderCropper">

<Thumb x:Name="CroppableArea" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background='{Binding CropperColor}' BorderBrush="Black" Opacity="0.2"
```

HeaderCropper class :

```
public static DependencyProperty ColorProperty;

static HeaderCroper()
{
ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CropperColor",
                                                typeof(Brush), typeof(HeaderCroper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
}

public Brush CropperColor
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ColorProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

HeaderCropper binding :

```
<DataTemplate>
                    <custom:HeaderCroper Panel.ZIndex="1" Width="50" Height="50" CropperHeight="{Binding Height,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
                                             CropperWidth="{Binding Width,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" 
                                             MaxCropperHeight="{Binding ElementName=Image,Path=RenderSize.Height}" 
                                             MaxCropperWidth="{Binding ElementName=Image,Path=RenderSize.Width}" 
                                             InfoCommand="{Binding InfoCommand}"
                                             InfoCommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                             DeleteCropperCommand="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
                                             DeleteCropperCommandParameter="{Binding Id}"
                                             CropperLeft="{Binding CropperLeft,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                                             CropperTop="{Binding CropperTop,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                                             MainCanvas ="{Binding ElementName=CropperCanvas,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                                             Canvas.Left="0"
                                             CropperColor="{Binding CropperColor,Mode=TwoWay,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                                             />
                </DataTemplate>
```

As you can see CropperColor parameter is passed but header cropper is ignoring it and not setting color. Any ideas?

UPDATE:
As I debug on private method key press I see that color is set but it is null while usercontroll is initializing.

Comment: `{Binding CropperColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}` should work.

Comment: @Clemens it doesn't.

Comment: Also make sure to adhere to naming conventions, i.e. rename `ColorProperty` to `CropperColorProperty`.